# Assigning javascript events in Asp.net Master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, button, menubar

I have a menu bar across the top of my web page with 4-5 asp.net buttons, the code is contained in the master page. I want all the buttons to do something on mouse over, so I am assigning the events in a loop like so:

```
 function pageLoad() {

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClass("headerButton");

    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        var b = buttons[i];

        b.onmouseover = function (element) {
            return function () {
                element.style.fontWeight = "bold";
            }
        } (b);
        b.onmouseout = function (element) {
            return function () {
                element.style.fontWeight = "normal";
            }
        } (b);
    }
```

Of course this only works on content pages. Page_Load never fires on the master page, I believe, so when I try putting this code on the master nothing ever occurs. Anyone know how this is meant to be done?

Comment: You call this script from Page_Load or through onload of the body tag?

Comment: I have a body tag in the master page and assigned this function to its onload event but nothing happens. No errors in firebug though.

Comment: Actually I got that to work, thanks. Do you think thats the best practice? It looks like script runs every time any content page loads, rather than just once.

Comment: I think it would be better to use jquery

Comment: Right but is there a way to ensure that the script runs only once, rather than everytime a content page loads?

Comment: No you cannot run this script once because each time a page is created the events must be associated with the newly created elements of the page.

Comment: This will run each time the page reloads on the client.  This is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be missing something... Why would you just not handle this with CSS?

```
.headerButton {
 font-weight: normal;
}

.headerButton:hover {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```